# How can I add event if multple checkboxes are checked?

Tags: javascript, jquery

https://jsfiddle.net/rsu1cjss/7/

I want show div (only this one)

```
<div class="two-colors box">You have selected <strong>two colors</strong> so i am here</div>
```

If red and green is checked

JS

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
    if($(this).attr("value")=="red"){
        $(".red").toggle();
    }
    if($(this).attr("value")=="green"){
        $(".green").toggle();
    }
    if($(this).attr("value")=="blue"){
        $(".blue").toggle();
    }
    if($(this).attr("value")=="yellow"){
        $(".yellow").toggle();
    }
});
```

HTML

```
<div>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="colorCheckbox" value="red"> red</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="colorCheckbox" value="green"> green</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="colorCheckbox" value="blue"> blue</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="colorCheckbox" value="yellow"> yellow</label>
</div>
<div class="red box">You have selected <strong>red checkbox</strong> so i am here</div>
<div class="green box">You have selected <strong>green checkbox</strong> so i am here</div>
<div class="blue box">You have selected <strong>blue checkbox</strong> so i am here</div>
<div class="yellow box">You have selected <strong>blue checkbox</strong> so i am here</div>
<div class="two-colors box">You have selected <strong>two colors</strong> so i am here</div>
```

CSS

```
   .box{
    padding: 20px;
    display: none;
    margin-top: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
.red{ background: #ff0000; }
.green{ background: #00ff00; }
.blue{ background: #0000ff; }
.yellow{ background: yellow; }
.two-colors {background: pink}
```

Answer (score 0):

In response to the click, check the `checked` properties on the red and green checkboxes, and only show the div if they're both true:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
    var red   = $("input[type=checkbox][value=red]")[0];
    var green = $("input[type=checkbox][value=green]")[0];
    $(".two-colors.box").toggle(red.checked && green.checked);
    // ...
});
```

Note that the single-div conditions in that code are *also* wrong: The checkbox's `value` is **always** going to be `"blue"`, `"yellow"`, etc.; what changes is whether the checkbox is checked. So you can use the value (`this.value`) to look up the div to show, and the `checked` property for the argument to `toggle`:

```
$("." + this.value).toggle(this.checked);
```

So:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
    // Handle the combined one
    var red   = $("input[type=checkbox][value=red]")[0];
    var green = $("input[type=checkbox][value=green]")[0];
    $(".two-colors.box").toggle(red.checked && green.checked);

    // Handle the singles:
    $("." + this.value).toggle(this.checked);
});
```

(Note that with `input` elements, in general `$(this).attr("value")` is **incorrect** for checking the value; use `$(this).val()` or just `this.value` as there's nothing special we need jQuery for in this case. The `value` **attribute** and the `value` **property** are not the same thing for `input` elements.)

**Live Example:**

```js
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {
  // Handle the combined one
  var red = $("input[type=checkbox][value=red]")[0];
  var green = $("input[type=checkbox][value=green]")[0];
  $(".two-colors.box").toggle(red.checked && green.checked);

  // Handle the singles:
  $("." + this.value).toggle(this.checked);
});
```

```css
.box {
  padding: 20px;
  display: none;
  margin-top: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
.red {
  background: #ff0000;
}
.green {
  background: #00ff00;
}
.blue {
  background: #0000ff;
}
.yellow {
  background: yellow;
}
.two-colors {
  background: pink
}
```

```html
<div>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="colorCheckbox" value="red">red</label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="colorCheckbox" value="green">green</label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="colorCheckbox" value="blue">blue</label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="colorCheckbox" value="yellow">yellow</label>
</div>
<div class="red box">You have selected <strong>red checkbox</strong> so i am here</div>
<div class="green box">You have selected <strong>green checkbox</strong> so i am here</div>
<div class="blue box">You have selected <strong>blue checkbox</strong> so i am here</div>
<div class="yellow box">You have selected <strong>blue checkbox</strong> so i am here</div>
<div class="two-colors box">You have selected <strong>two colors</strong> so i am here</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Or with more jQuery: ;-)

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
    // Handle the combined one
    var redChecked = $("input[type=checkbox][value=red]").is(":checked");
    var greenChecked = $("input[type=checkbox][value=green]").is(":checked");
    $(".two-colors.box").toggle(redChecked && greenChecked);

    // Handle the singles:
    var $this = $(this);
    $("." + $this.val()).toggle($this.is(":checked"));
});
```

```js
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
    // Handle the combined one
    var redChecked = $("input[type=checkbox][value=red]").is(":checked");
    var greenChecked = $("input[type=checkbox][value=green]").is(":checked");
    $(".two-colors.box").toggle(redChecked && greenChecked);

    // Handle the singles:
    var $this = $(this);
    $("." + $this.val()).toggle($this.is(":checked"));
});
```

```css
.box {
  padding: 20px;
  display: none;
  margin-top: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
.red {
  background: #ff0000;
}
.green {
  background: #00ff00;
}
.blue {
  background: #0000ff;
}
.yellow {
  background: yellow;
}
.two-colors {
  background: pink
}
```

```html
<div>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="colorCheckbox" value="red">red</label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="colorCheckbox" value="green">green</label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="colorCheckbox" value="blue">blue</label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="colorCheckbox" value="yellow">yellow</label>
</div>
<div class="red box">You have selected <strong>red checkbox</strong> so i am here</div>
<div class="green box">You have selected <strong>green checkbox</strong> so i am here</div>
<div class="blue box">You have selected <strong>blue checkbox</strong> so i am here</div>
<div class="yellow box">You have selected <strong>blue checkbox</strong> so i am here</div>
<div class="two-colors box">You have selected <strong>two colors</strong> so i am here</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

Note that this assumes the only checkboxes with the values `red` and `green` are the ones you care about. If you need to narrow it down further, give them a class or ID.